# Why does the sum function give an "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values" error for a 1x3 double?

Tags: matlab

I was trying to get `k` floating-point numbers that sum to 1. I found a [code sample](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/358920-how-to-make-3-random-numbers-that-sum-to-1) to do this:

```
row = rand(1, k)
row = row / sum(row)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Array indices must be positive integers or logical values

The problem is definitely with the `sum` function, because when I try the following:

```
row = rand(1, k)

% Sum of all of the numbers
a = 0

for index = 1:k
    a = a + row(index)
end

row = row / a
```

it does exactly what I expect.

Can someone explain why `sum` throws that error here (especially since the comments on the linked code sample implies that extremely similar code worked for them)? Is there some way that I can fix this?

Comment: Works fine on my end. Are you getting this for any/all `k`? Which MATLAB version?

Comment: My _guess_ is that you have a variable called `sum` in your workspace. This takes precedence over the function `sum`.